# Dynamically update Site/Wordpress Address

Tags: site-url, ip, linux

Is anyone aware of a PHP method to use the linux server's currently assigned IP address as the Wordpress Address and Site Address? I'm not *too worried* about breaking the site, because it's experimental. This can be done either with the wp-config.php file or the web-view.

I'm busy with experimental work where the server will be on a remote location, and has to run WordPress on whatever IP it gets - and also because I'm on a different IP Range than the server.

**Psuedo-Example:**
WordPress Address (URL): `$GetIPAddressEth0`

Site Address (URL): `$GetIPAddressEth0`

**THUS:**
Server is on network "A": IP Leased = 172.16.22.4, so $GetIPAddressEth0 is the 172.16.22.4 IP.

**OR**
Server is on network "B": IP Leased = 10.20.4.2, so $GetIPAddressEth0 is the 10.20.4.2 IP.

Comment: You could look at this from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5800927/2932678